# Bibtex error in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I tried to build my tex file, I have already config my JSON file of LaTex workshop, it looks like this:

```
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
        {
            "name": "xelatex",
            "command": "xelatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "latexmk",
            "command": "latexmk",
            "args": [
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "-pdf",
                "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bibtex",
            "command": "bibtex",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "biber",
            "command": "biber",
            "args": [
                "%DOCFILE%"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [
        {
            "name": "XeLaTeX",
            "tools": [
                "xelatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "PDFLaTeX",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "BibTeX",
            "tools": [
                "bibtex"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "LaTeXmk",
            "tools": [
                "latexmk"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "pdflatex -> biber -> pdflatex*2",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex",
                "biber",
                "pdflatex",
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
    ],
```

However, when I tried to build my tex file, I still got the error: `i found no citation commands`

An example of my tex file is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}    \usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\theoremstyle{definition}
```

The error message is reported by `beamer` package.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:

The error message is like this:

[image: error]

Comment: well, do you have any `\cite` commands in your document?

Comment: So far nope, the error is reported just in \usepackage{beamer}.

Comment: no point  in loading graphicx, hyperref, xcolor, beamer has loaded them already

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that.

Comment: if you have no `\cite` (or `\nocite`) the message you quote is expected.

Comment: Also no need to load amsmath, beamer loads this automatically, and float is only of so much use in a documentclass without floating mechanism...

Comment: Also in your title you mention bibtex, but your code uses biblatex, which needs to be compiled with biber and not bibtex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added a screen shoot of the error message, could you plz take a look at that?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks for that info :)

Comment: why re you running bibtex not biber but why are you using biber or bibtex if you have no `\cite` ? They can only format citations that you `\cite` they can not make them out of thin air

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am a noob of latex, sorry for the inconvenience. I will use `\cite` later since I just started this doc. I am really confused that how to use biber correctly.

Comment: @AllonsyJia As said in your previous question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/661756/36296 you should clean up your preamble. Only use the packages you need and don't just copy from random templates.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, you r right. I didn't make my template clearly. I just did that. Really thanks for your advice.

Comment: is `%DOCFILE%"` your full `filename.tex` ? if so you are going `bibtex filename.tex`  which will pass the tex file to bibtex (and biber) so give errors. You need `filename` with no extension, however that is expressed in the json